# html on mobile device - Allow vertical scroll when horizontal scroll element touched

Tags: html, scroll

I have a horizontal scroll div inside of a vertical scroll div. The vertical and horizontal scroll works fine, but when I start the vertical scroll by touching the horizontal scroll div, then the horizontal div takes control, and prevents the vertical scroll.

If placing a horizontal scroll inside a vertical scroll is not good practice on mobile sites, then I will find another way. If okay, I would like to have the horizontal and vertical scroll behave in a smart way- that is, the site knows if you are trying to do either a vertical scroll, or horizontal scroll. Not necessary to have simultaneous scroll.

Comment: Could you re-create this issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RowanG1/r571xh1v/1/